# C - Stack around the variable 'name' was corrupted

Tags: c, arrays, function

I've tried to handle this error but no success. I have the next function which is supposed to calculate the average age:

```
float CalculateAverageAge(int ages[],int size, const float &average)
{
    float sumOfAges,averageOfAges;
    sumOfAges=0;

    for(int counter=1;counter<=size;counter++)
    {
        sumOfAges=sumOfAges+ages[counter];
    }
    averageOfAges=sumOfAges/size;

    return averageOfAges;
}
```

And this one, which is supposed to print some information only from the persons that live in Texas:

```
void DisplayMembersInTexas(char names[],char states[],int size)
{
    for(int counter=1;counter<=size;counter++)
        if(states[counter]=="Texas")//  here, another error: operand types are incompatible ("char" and "const char *")
            printf("%d members lives in Texas");
}
```

And the main function:

```
void main()
{
    char names[50];
    int ages[50];
    char states[50];

    int count;
    float average;

    char name,state;
    int age;

    printf("How many familly members do you have? ");
    scanf("%d",&count);

    for(int counter=1;counter<=count;counter++)
    {
        printf("Please enter member name:");
        scanf("%s",&name);
        printf("Please enter member age:");
        scanf("%d",&age);
        printf("Please enter familly member state:");
        scanf("%s",&state);

        names[counter]=name;
        ages[counter]=age;
        states[counter]=state;

        printf("\n");
    }

    CalculateAverageAge(ages,count,average);
    printf("The average age of all familly members is:",average);
    DisplayMembersInTexas(names,states,count);
}
```

I receive the following errors:

- Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'name' was corrupted
- Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'state' was corrupted

Any hints on how can I handle these errors ?

Comment: `name` and `state` are single chars, not arrays of chars, so doing things like `scanf("%s",&name);` isn't appropriate.

Comment: So, I should use `printf("%c",&name)` ? I would like it on C @Lightness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THere is a misunderstanding about parameters:

```
char name,state;   // ATTENTION these are single chars !! Not strings
```

When you do the input:

```
 scanf("%s",&name);  // You request for a string but have only place for a single char
```

all the entered chars will be copied to the memory location starting at `name`, but not for 1 char, but all the chars entered plus the trailing '\0'.  So you overflow your buffer of 1 char, which corrupt the stack (i.e. local memory of the function).  For `state` it's exactly the same.

## Solution 1: build on c-style:

```
char names[50][31];
char states[50][31];
char name[31],state[31];
...
scanf("%30s",name);
...
scanf("%30s",state);
strcpy (names[counter],name);
strcpy (states[counter],state);
```

As the names and states array are now arrays of array of chars you need to adapt the called function:

```
void DisplayMembersInTexas(char names[][31], char states[][31], int size) 
{
    int members=0; 
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= size; counter++)
        if (strcmp(states[counter],"Texas")==0)  // they are equal when strcmp()==0 
            members++;
    printf("%d members lives in Texas", members);
}
```

The main advantage of this approach is that it uses the c input/putput that you know.  However, the fact that the C-strings are in fact a null terminated array of chars is cumbersome to manage.

## Solution 2: adopt plain C++:

```
string names[50];
string states[50];
string name,state;
...
cin >> name;
...
cin >> state;
names[counter]=name;
states[counter]=state;
```

You'd then change the called function accordingly:

```
void DisplayMembersInTexas(string names[], string states[], int size)
{
     int members=0;
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= size; counter++)
        if (states[counter]=="Texas")
            members++;
    cout << members << " members lives in Texas";
}
```

This approach requires you to digg a litle bit more into C++ especially in iostreams which is different from what you know.  But the c++ `string` are very powerfull.  You can manipulate them almost like build in type, and they have no limits regarding their size.

Comment: Thank you, @Christophe. I've made the changes(from the C version) but now, I have a problem with parameters from `DisplayMembersInTexas(names,states,count);`. It tells me that: `argument of type "char (*)[31]" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *`. Any suggestion on how to modify those parameters ?

Comment: @Alexander ok !  I've added the required adaptations in the post.

Comment: I completed and understood @Christophe. Now, I don't reveive any error but as far as it seems nothing is printed out for the average function. And more, for the texas one, it says `0 members lives in Texas` even though this is not correct. Did I missed something with those parameters from each function when declaring and calling them ?

Comment: I was about to say that comparison is case sensitive, but I noticed that I forgot `==0` .  All my appologies for that !

Comment: It works @Christophe, perfectly and I even get the algorithm. A little digging into strcmp() function helped me out. But still no success with the average function. Still doesn't print anything

Comment: Ok !  you pass argument `average` by reference to this function but you never store a value in it.  You then return an average but you don't use the returned value.  Just put `average=averageOfAges;` before your return statement.  Finally you call `printf()`, but you do neither say it to print out a float, nor the corresponing argument:  `printf("Average is %f\n", average);`

Comment: It won't allow me to put: `average=averageOfAges;` . It says: `const float &average. Error: expression should be a modifiable lvalue`

Comment: Ok:  remove the const on the line of the function definition

Comment: @Alexander - if this answer helped you, you can help the community (and Christophe) by marking it as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

When input `state` (and also for `name`) like this

```
scanf("%s",&state);
```

you broke memory, because `state` has only one byte. It must be

```
scanf("%c",&state);
```

I think your datatypes is inappropriate... `state` (as well as `name`) have to be array (char[...]) not just one `char`, and `states` should be `char[][]`.

And also use

```
if( strcmp(states, "Texas") == 0)  // string comparison in C
```

instead of

```
if(states[counter]=="Texas")   // address comparison
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays start at index 0, not 1.

Furthermore, you're treating objects of type `char` as strings, which they are not.

You tagged your question C++, so I suggest using `std::string`. If you're stuck on C, you're going to need multidimensional arrays and more complicated logic than you've got now, because arrays are not assignable.

Comment: I'll remove the C++ tag. I will try to re-edit the code using multidimensional arrays. But why should I use them ? Whi I cannot use simple arrays ?

Comment: @Alexander: Why can you not use simple arrays of `char` to store multiple strings? Because a single `char` is not a single string. It is a single character. In C, a string is already an array of `char`. So to have an array of strings, you need to have an array of arrays of `char`.